# Invoking a function with jsonp

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some html5 postMessage code:

```
    window.addEventListener("message", FA.recieveMessage, false);
```

That listener invokes this function:

```
FA.recieveMessage = function(e){
if (e.data == "closeFA"){
            console.log("Type of data: "+e.data);
}
};
```

Now on ie8 this code doesnt work, cause it doesnt support html5 messaging. So I thought if there is a way to invoke that function by sending an ajax request of type jsonp!?

Is there a way to emulate messaging with jsonp?

if i do send jsonp request to another server, does it mean that it is a new request and it wont be aware of all the events that were triggered now?

**UPDATE**

Okay here is what I want. I want to close an iframe. So on one page, I have got this javascript:

```
        $.ajax({url:      'http://api.apps.com/html/'+FA.appID,
      data:      {},
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      timeout:  10000,
      jsonp: "closeIFrame"
      });
```

This should instruct the apps/html page to invoke the closeIframe function is that right?

```
function closeIFrame() {
    jQuery("#fa-iframe-container").fadeOut(300, function(){ jQuery(this).remove(); });
FA.bannerShown = false;
```

}

Comment: Would [long polling](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7193380/451969) help?

Comment: not sure if this is relevant, at least not what i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes technically you could emulate messaging with jsonp, each call will be a new  request but the session will be available so the jsonp service could be state aware.

***Update***

In my experience you don't call functions within a file instead each file represents a function so you may have services like:

http://example.com/add?message=hello

http://example.com/get

Comment: see my update again... calling file is not in my agenda to be honest, but if there is no choice , i will have to. So you are saying adding another javascript file?.. is my script above is wrong?

Comment: When I was talking about calling files I was talking about the file containing the web service.

Comment: That sounds a lot like long-polling to me, regardless of the means of action. It's a push.